# How were duplicate Minecraft usernames created?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Normally, Minecraft usernames have to be unique. However, there are some duplicate Minecraft usernames that still exist. How were these users created?

**Here's an example:**

https://namemc.com/search?q=shaft

Comment: I'd also like to add that there are invalid Minecraft usernames too:
[https://namemc.com/profile/internet.com.1](https://namemc.com/profile/internet.com.1)

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate Minecraft nicknames as far as I'm concerned can be made because:

1. Capitalization usually matters (ex: **s**haft and **S**haft), though it can be placed wherever.
2. Different characters that look the same (ex: Sh**a**ft and Sh**а**ft), so a Cyrillic е would look the same as a Latin e, but be different Unicode characters.

As for illegal nicknames, it's either because of hacks or being really old.

Comment: Capitalization doesn't matter

Comment: as far as Minecraft is concerned you won't be allowed to create duplicate account usernames with the only difference being capitialization

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example username you gave, I have found two possible reasons for what you found.

- One of the usernames is "shaft" and the other is "Shaft" (notice capitalization). This may be causing this "duplicate" but I was under the impression that usernames were not case sensitive.
- The other possible reason I found is they have different UUIDs. One starts b7, the other starts e5.

---

I'm not sure if these are the actual reasons, but this is the best I found given your example.